# How to create window in dll application with wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, dll, wxwidgets, createwindow

I want to make dll application with wxWidgets.Long time I use c++ Builder for making dll application but I also want to work on Visual Studio.Please help!

I search on google about this but did't find any information about this or just have 2 example and one is didn't work and one is in wxWidgets folder and I cant understand how to make it work.

Comment: You probably want to learn these 2 concepts separately.

Comment: ***I use c++ Builder for making dll application but I also want to work on Visual Studio.*** Generally compilers will not produce compatible c++ binaries that can be shared between different c++ implementations. If you stick to a c++ standard likc c++14 you could use your source code to recompile your dll project in Visual Studio you may want to use CMake to make it easier to switch between compilers.

Comment: There are a plethora of examples of using wxWidgets with Visual Studio.  I recommend using wxFormBuilder to create the designs and layouts of your windows.  It will also generate the wxWidgets compatible code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you for your answer.I didn't know about wxFormBuilder.I add dll entry point to the my exe project and changed it to the dll project.its works.